# Change default Schema name in Cleardb add-on on Heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku, cleardb

I have provisioned a ClearDB addon to my app running on Heroku. I am able to manage the database using MySQLWorkbench. However the account created to access the database has no permissions to change the default schema name created nor does it have permission to create a new schema. How can I change the schema name?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a multi-tenant ClearDB database, it cannot be renamed.  But if you are interested in spending some money, they will be happy to help you rename it.

https://getsatisfaction.com/cleardb/topics/is_it_possible_to_rename_database